# Where do I put my resque-retry failure backend code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, resque-retry

The [resque-retry](https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry) gem's README discusses changing the failure backend implementation when implementing.

> `MultipleWithRetrySuppression` is a multiple failure backend, with retry suppression.
>
> Here's an example, using the Redis failure backend:
>
> ```
> require 'resque-retry'
> require 'resque/failure/redis'
>
> # require your jobs & application code.
>
> Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis]
> Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression
> ```
>
> If a job fails, but **can and will** retry, the failure details wont be logged in the Redis failed queue *(visible via resque-web)*.
>
> If the job fails, but **can't or won't** retry, the failure will be logged in the Redis failed queue, like a normal failure *(without retry)* would.

I'm not sure where in my Rails app that code should go.  Should I just place it into any random initializer file, e.g. `config/initializers/resque.rb`?  Or is there some other place in my app where it should go?  The documentation is not clear.

Comment: I think you're right, need to place these lines in initializer

Comment: you should probably create a PR for resque-retry with updated documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an initializer is the best bet.  Accepting this as the best answer unless someone comes along with a better suggestion.